# Trying to print out data from database

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to print out data from my database in python using the mySQL connect library. I want to print out all of the tuples in a specific table, however, it is not coming out how I would like. Right now each tuple is printing out like this:

```
(u'User1',)
(u'User2',)
(u'User3',)
```

And I would like it just to print out as

```
User1
User2
User3
```

Below is my python function:

```
def show_player_table():
    query = ("SELECT name FROM field_player")
    cursor.execute(query)

    for result in cursor:
        print("{}".format(result))
```

Any ideas? I hope I have provided enough info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extract the first object of the tuple; I would even check if the tuple has any object:

```
def show_player_table():
    query = ("SELECT name FROM field_player")
    cursor.execute(query)

    for result in cursor:
        if len(result):
            print("{}".format(result[0]))
```